# I stand by you vs I'll stand by you

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Is the phrase "I stand by you" grammatically correct on its own?
I know there is a song called "I'll stand by you" and understand the implication of "will". I want to use the phrase "I stand by you" so that it doesn't infringe on a potential copyright issue.
Many thanks

Comment: _I stand by you_ or _I am standing by you_ can be used to mean that you are supporting the person now.

Comment: "I'll stand by you" implies future support (as well as probably current support). "I stand by you" implies support now (and possibly future support). It's more a question of emphasis than grammar.

Comment: Using the phrase "I'll stand by you" wouldn't infringe on copyright, even as a song title, as it's a common English phrase, if that's the only issue.